# Has Neil Gaiman's Sandman ever appeared in a Justice League comic?

Tags: dc, justice-league, the-sandman

Quite a few times, the DC characters have appeared in the Sandman books, but has he ever appeared in the Justice League or any other DC comic book ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Daniel-incarnation of the Sandman [makes a guest apperance in JLA #22-23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Hall#Appearances_outside_of_The_Sandman).

[image]
[image]

Comment: o_0 I need to read this right now!

Comment: Are those all his frames, or does he have a recurring role in those issues?

Comment: He's central in this one storyline, where a lot takes place in the dreaming. But I don't know about him appearing outside of this 2-issue story.

Comment: Daniel also made a few appearances in JSA as part of a long story arc involving Hector and Lyta Hall. As far as I know, JSA #80 is his most recent appearance.