# Did "24 Hours" happen in any other comic besides Sandman?

Tags: dc, comics, the-sandman

In *[The Sandman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman_(Vertigo))* #6 ("24 Hours"), [Doctor Destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Destiny) abuses [Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_(comics))'s ruby to wreak havoc on a global scale.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Preludes_%26_Nocturnes) that Dee only affected the poor inhabitants of that diner, but I'm pretty sure that Dee's actions have effects on a larger scale than that. On page 11 of the comic, a news report shows "his jewel in action":

> [image: Dee watching a TV. Caption: "Nearly as much enjoyment as he gets from watching his jewel in action." Reporter: "News at six. Is *everybody* going *crazy?* Reports are coming in from across the state about a wave of *madness*, *suicide* and *bad dreams*..." Caption: "Pleasure."]

<sup>*The Sandman* #6 page 11</sup>

And on the next page:

> [image: Dee and diners seated, watching the TV. Caption: "Hour 11: He catches up on the news." TV: "...nightmares, sleeplessness and insanity reported earlier on local news is shaping up to be a planet-wide phenomenon."]
>
> TV: "...nightmares, sleeplessness and insanity reported earlier on local news is shaping up to be a **planet-wide phenomenon**."

Additionally, several large disasters are shown on the opening pages of the next issue (#7 "Sound and Fury"), including a hospital on fire and an airplane that crashed on a freeway.

Some Justice League members, John Constantine, and other DC characters receive cameo appearances (or more) in *[Preludes and Nocturnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Preludes_%26_Nocturnes)*, so this takes place in a (the?) universe with mainstream characters. I would imagine that the superheroes or JLI in this world would attempt to mount some sort of response to this catastrophe.

**Were the events of "24 Hours" shown in any other comic?**

Comment: [I copied](https://imgur.com/a/OMOd9) the images in your question from my digital editions - mine appear to be of slightly better quality and higher resolution.

Comment: Oh, I think I misread your question. I thought you were asking about the effects of this event further in the _Sandman_ series; I'm sorry, but I won't be able to give a better answer - I'm not well-versed in older JL comics (you should've seen my fiasco [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154334/70236)).

Comment: Thank for the images, @Gallifreyan; that's what happens when you use the library copy, I guess. Yeah, I was kinda asking about *other* comics, but I guess it's nice to see that there are pingbacks later in Sandman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those events did not occur in any other comics.

As Gallifreyan pointed out in his answer, they are referenced again later in another *Sandman* story arc, but that was par for the course in that series; most of that series' story arcs involved events and/or characters mentioned or alluded to in the initial issues. But as far as showing the effects of Doctor Destiny's shenanigans with the ruby in, like, *Justice League* or *Superman* or some other title, nope.

Answer (score 8):

Off top of my head I can think of one mention of those events.

Remember Judy, who broke up with her girlfriend, Donna?

[image: "Hi. Rose? Yeah, it's me. Judy. Listen -- have you seen Donna today? Well, we had a fight last night, and I'm sort of worried... Split up? No, of course we haven't. It's just -- here mom? You think she might have gone back to her mom?"]
<sub>(Click for a larger version)</sub>

She appears in Donna's (who calls herself Foxglove by then) nightmare in *A Game of You* (the sixth volume), which we may count as events of *24 Hours* being shown in another comic.

[image: "It's me. Judy" "Judy? You can't be Judy. You're dead." "Yeah. Dead as a dodo. It's a real shit isn't it? And it's your fault. You know that?" "Mine?" "Sure it is If you hadn't taken off, I wouldn't have been hanging around in that damned diner... And I'd still be able to taste, and feel, and dream..."]

Other than that, there seems to be no echo of those events later in the story. Given that the world also houses the Justice League, it is quite probably that those freak events were forgotten when some *other* unrelated freak events broke out, as it often happens with Justice League and their neverending quarrels with their neverending archenemies.

Dream could also have repaired the damage done, and erased the memories of these unfortunate events.